# How to get files from commits excluding merge commits in PullRequest using Rest API in Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I've implemented my code **Pull Request -> Commits -> Changes**.
But when I check, there are a few merge commits too which are actually not required.
[image]

Now the actual problem is that those merge commits are not required.
If I consider those commits I get N number of extra files which are of no use.
Now I need to get the exact or real **list of files** ***(with ccommit id)*** present in a pull request like in Files tab in UI.

[image]

So can we exclude merge commits during retrieval of all commits in PR or any alternative way?